# Zooming issue in css?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```html
<h1>Some data</h1>
```

```css
h1{
    margin: 50px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    padding:10px 50px 10px;
    color:red;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #fff;
}
h1:before{
    content:'';
    width:100%; height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:-1px; left:0;
    background:red;
    z-index:-1;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg);
    transform: skewX(-20deg);

    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
    transform-origin:0 0;
    background: #fff;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gyvprwex/25/

The problem is when I zoom out (on Chrome and IE 11), in some cases the child (`:before`) seemed to be higher the parent, and in some cases the child seemed to be shorter.

[image]

How can I fix this zooming issue?

Answer (score 0):

DEMO  [Codepen](http://codepen.io/dannibla/debug/gLaNpQ)

Here, i have modified your code:

```css
* {
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

html {
 position: relative;
 margin: 2%;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 540px;
}

html h1 {
 max-width: 100%;
 text-align:center;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

html:hover h1 {
 -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
 transform: scale(1.1);
}

h1 {
 margin: 50px;
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
 z-index:1;
 padding:10px 50px 10px;
 color:red;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 background: #fff;
}

h1:before {
 content:'';
 width:100%; height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 top:-1px; left:0;
 background:red;
 z-index:-1;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
 -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg);
 transform: skewX(-20deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
 -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
 transform-origin:0 0;
 background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h1>Some data</h1>
```